# QT identifying selected item from a scene

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4dotnet

I have been creating an QT application but  struck in a place. I have created own custom scene class deriving from QGraphicsScene from where I add my items like car,bus etc to the screen .

```
void Scene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{

    if (mouseEvent->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
        return;

    DiagramItem *item;
    switch (myMode) {
        case InsertItem:
            item = new DiagramItem(myItemType, myItemMenu);
            addItem(item);
            item->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
            emit itemInserted(item);
            break;
```

As you can see from the above code I have a DiagramItem class which is derived from QGraphicsPixmapItem for adding different item to scene.

```
 switch (myDiagramType) {
        case Bus:
             setPixmap( QPixmap( Dir+"/images/bus1.jpg"  ));
            break;
        case Car:
            setPixmap( QPixmap( Dir+"/images/car4scene.png"  ));
            break;
        case Truck:
```

What I want to achieve here is,When I select my item from the scene (car or bus ), I want to know which vehicle has been selected either car or bus or truck . I have no clue how to go on this . Can any one help me . I get the selected item like this from scene .

void MainWindow::itemSelected(QGraphicsItem *item) // signal sent from scene.
{

```
DiagramItem *ItemSelect = qgraphicsitem_cast<DiagramItem *>(item);
```

//  like to know 'ItemSelect' is car or bus or anyother vehicle

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DiagramItem is of your own design, merely keep the type internally and provide a method to query it. Alternatively, keep a hash where key is DiagramItem * and value is the type.

Answer (score 3):

A way to store custom data in a QGraphicsItem without deriving a custom class is to use [`data()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#data) and `setData()`. You can use the stored data for identification.